# Tell network-manager to suspend

Tags: networkmanager

I would like to set up a network between two computers. They are connected to the internet through wireless, but as soon as Network-Manager sees the wired connection, it takes down the wireless connection.

How can I tell Network-Manager to ignore the wired connection? Or tell Network-Manager to pause doing anything until I am finished with the wired connection.

I tried putting the connection into `/etc/network/interfaces`. It did not get Network-Manager stop pulling down the wireless connection.